# Split tag elements into differently named tags using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, split, tags

I have a `<Content>` tag in which I have a string for example:

`"Hello   how   do   you   do   END"`

What I'm trying to do is split that string by "\t" and put each word into a different named tag like so:

```
<a>Hello</a>
<b>how</b>
<c>do</c>
```

I split them using tokenize:

```
<xsl:template match="*:Content/text()">
   <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,'\t')">
    <b xmlns="">
     <xsl:sequence select="."/>
    </b>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I just need to be able to differentiate the words later on without knowing them.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could format the `position()` with the right format e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="test">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\s+')">
              <xsl:element name="{format-integer(position(), 'a')}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzRm

For XSLT 2 you can use `xsl:number` to format the `position()`:

```
 <xsl:template match="test">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\s+')">
              <xsl:variable name="element-name">
                  <xsl:number format="a" value="position()"/>
              </xsl:variable>
              <xsl:element name="{$element-name}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/pPqsHSV

However, it might make more sense to simply create an element of the same name with the position in an attribute:

```
  <xsl:template match="test">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\s+')">
              <word pos="{position()}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </word>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzRm/1

Comment: The first one is exactly what I need. It's just that I need the XSLT to be version 2 or  1 because format-integer isn't recognized.

Comment: @banb, see the edit, if you have `tokenize` the you should have XSLT 2 at least and can alternatively use `xsl:number` to format the `position()` as needed.